# Add filter/parameter in calculated field tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I'm trying to create calculated field in tableau, my below query is showing valid, however I want to give filter or parameter to it. For ex: I have a field called Account number and I want my below query to show sum of all the quarters revenue on account number level.

```
Sum(If ([Qtr]='2019-Q1' OR [Qtr]='2019-Q2' OR [Qtr]='2019-Q3' OR [Qtr]='2019-Q4') 
THEN FLOAT([Revenue]) END)
```

Comment: Thought logic used in both will be same.

Comment: Please just tag the actual RDBMS you are interested in. People don't appreciate over tagging.

Comment: I've removed them for you, please add back the single RDBMS of interest.

Answer (score 0):

Your logic will work.
For parameter: Create a parameter with String data type, add all field names to it. Then create a calculated field based on the parameter list. Add that calculated field to row shelf then change Parameter, the above formula will be recalculated.
For Filter: You can add filter directly.

Answer (score 0):

**1st option:**

Add Account number as row in your worksheet

Create a Parameter String with values: 2019-Q1, 2019-Q2, 2019-Q3, 2019-Q4

Update your calculated field to:

```
If [Qtr]='Parameter Value' THEN FLOAT([Revenue]) END
```

Add this field as text and the value of sum will be for only that Qtr period

**2nd option:**

Add Account number as row in your worksheet

Create a Parameter String with values: 2019-Q1, 2019-Q2, 2019-Q3, 2019-Q4

Update your calculated field to:

```
[Qtr]='Parameter Value'
```

Add this field to the filters and the whole worksheet will filter on that Qtr period

*You can also add another parameter for the year to be more flexible on the years*